# Does MOND respect linear superposition of gravitational field intensities?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, modified-gravity, galaxy-rotation-curve

Does Milgrom's MOND respect linear superposition of gravitational field intensities as Newtonian gravity does?

Comment: I think this is a good question mainly because I'm finding frequent references to MOND in the many attempts to explain the huge disparity between Dark Energy &/or Dark Matter and observable matter:  Physicist Sabine Hossenfelder, for instance, has a raft of videos out about these subjects.

Comment: Found this  review of Mond theories  http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/The_MOND_paradigm_of_modified_dynamics by Milgrom

Answer (score 1):

MOND is generically nonlinear. This means that the effect felt by a test particle under the gravitational influence of a system of masses is not the simple sum of the effects produced by the constituents separately. (Linearity is rather unique to Newtonian gravity. The theory of general relativity is also nonlinear.)

[scholarpedia.org/article/The_MOND_paradigm_of_modified_dynamics](https://scholarpedia.org/article/The_MOND_paradigm_of_modified_dynamics)